# Setting install_name building boost 1.60.0 on MacOS X?

Tags: python, c++, macos, boost, linker

Using the standard:

```
% ./bootstrap.sh
% sudo ./b2 install
```

Builds Boost v1.60.0 fine on MacOS 10.11.2, however the install_name entries on the libboost_*.dylib files are relative, without absolute paths:

```
% otool -D /usr/local/lib/libboost_python.dylib
```

Produces

```
/usr/local/lib/libboost_python.dylib:
libboost_python.dylib
```

This becomes a problem attempting to use libboost_python.dylib with Apple's standard python which complains about unsafe use of relative rpath when importing a library using Boost.Python:

```
% python
>>> import mylibrary

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/path/to/mylibrary.so, 2): Library not loaded: libboost_chrono.dylib
  Referenced from: /path/to/mylibrary.so
  Reason: unsafe use of relative rpath libboost_chrono.dylib in /path/to/mylibrary.so with restricted binary
```

Using:

```
sudo install_name_tool -id /usr/local/lib/libboost_chrono.dylib /usr/local/lib/libboost_chrono.dylib
```

almost fixes this, except references from one libboost_ library to another (i.e. libboost_thread linking to libboost_atomic) remain relative during compiling boost, so the install_name_tool would need to be run during the compilation. Alternatively using a non-standard Python  doesn't complain. But I'd like to be able to specify the install_name is correctly generated when building Boost, ideally as parameters to b2, but haven't be able to determine how? I tried (admittedly a long-shot):

```
sudo ./b2 dll-path=/usr/local/lib install
```

Without success.